# Prevent NestedScrollView top to go up

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, listview

I am trying to create an app that his first activity will look like shazam:

First: As you can see the listview is below the Shazam Icon.

[image]

Second: When I have start to roll up the list, it goes up on the Shazam icon.

[image]

Until now, I have created a NestedScrollView, bit when I does it the top goes up and not stays in the same position when I scroll the listView.

This is my code so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <include layout="@layout/top"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />
```

How an I make the top not to go up, but the list view will go? Like Shaxam does?